# grep and regular expressions - meta/wildcard characters

Tags: regex, r

This is a bare minimal example of a larger more complex dataset, just trying to get my head around something.

```
> grep("X10\\.1+",c("X10.10","X10.11","X10.12"))
[1] 1 2 3
```

Now I would have expected only `2` to have been returned, since '+' is supposed to be '1 or more of the preceding element'. I thought escaping the period (which I have to deal with so want to keep it in the example) could have been causing the issue.

```
> grep("X101+",c("X1010","X1011","X1012"))
[1] 1 2 3
```

So, my understanding of the functionality of '+' is wrong?

CONCLUSION:

Thanks @James. So my understanding was the + was 'ANOTHER 1 or more of the preceding element' as opposed to what it actually means, which is 'JUST 1 or more of the preceding element'.

11+ would have done what I was thinking (having an ADDITIONAL 1 or more 1's after the first 1 etc). Cheers

Comment: hi, can you explain why you expect only 2 to have been returned?

Comment: Hi Nikos. I'd expect only 2 based on the my understanding of + which is 1 or more of the preceding element. So 1+ should be TRUE for 11 or 111 or 1111 but not for 10 or 12 etc as 0 is a different character to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to signify that after any number of 1s, you want to match the end of the string. You use `$` to do this.

```
grep("X10\\.1+$",c("X10.10","X10.11","X10.12"))
[1] 2
```

Similarly, `^` matches the start of the string if you want to restrict that the match starts `X10.`, rather than `PX10.` for instance which would be matched by the existing regex.

Comment: Thanks James. I had toyed around with $. What I don't get is that + is 1 or more of the preceding right? Not zero or more. So, X10.10 should be a false because there isn't AT LEAST another 1 after the first one. I could understand what you're saying if it was picking up X10.110 as a true but picking up X10.10 still seems wrong to me.

Comment: I'm not saying I think you're wrong :) I'd have thought if using an * you might pick up 1 2 and 3, but surely a + requires it to have a .11 regardless of the use of $?

Comment: No, + means one or more instances of the symbol, including the original one, ie `1+` is a single entity meaning one or more `1`.

Comment: +rep, why does he need to match the end of the string with $

Comment: @Nikos Because otherwise it matches on strings where the pattern is included, which is the problem the OP is posting.

Comment: Ah! I get you @James. The intricacies of reg exp. Clearly I thought it was 'AN ADDITIONAL' 1 or more yada yada yada. Thanks for taking the time to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the preceding element is the digit '1' which is present at that position in all 3 elements.  Your prior understanding of '+' is correct.